# pseudocode notation / find a pair such that when you subtract one from the other it should equal to zero in mod n

Tags: algorithm

it has been a while I worked anything in pseudo code.

```
    Let a ∈ A
    A := A \ { a }
```

Can you tell me, specifically what this part is -> A := A \ { a }
a should be the set members, so a pair?

Comment: A := A \ { a } means that remove a from set A.

Comment: If you don't understand how to read this style of pseudocode, you should study the part of the textbook before they started using it. Or talk to your instructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize all items of the array X by `-1`

For at most m steps:

1. Pick a number from the `set A` and keep it in the variable `a`
2. Remove `a` from the `set A`
3. Calculate `r = a mod n` (remainder of `a / n`)
4. If `X[r] = -1` (there is no `a` such that `r = a mod n` before), then set `X[r] = a`, Else, (there was `a` such that `r = a mod n` before) so return the `pair (X[r], a)` which both have the same remainder respect with `n`.

Comment: Thanks, so there may be multiple pairs but we are choosing "a pair" right? And we know that this algorithm will give us the correct pair because we take a, and then we look up the remainder of a / n so that when we take:     a - (remainder of a / n) we will have 0 in mod n.  what would be the run time complexity? considering n and m.

Comment: For every element we are going through the initial list, and look into the rest of the list(?) but we only do look ups (not iterate through). So would it be only m? But then I am also asked the run time complexity if n is a constant.

Comment: @nich You are welcome. You might have more than one pair, but in your algorithm, you return the first pair once one is found. Note that because m > n, then we will definitely have at least one pair that have the same remainder over n.

Comment: @nich Regarding the complexity, it depends on the details of your implementation. If you always use the first item in the set, then no need to find and remove it in line 2. Otherwise, you have to spend O(log(m)) in terms of finding each item in the ordered set. You can use arrays instead of sets to make it cheaper I think. Go through items in array A, and calculate r = a mod n to put in X[r].

Comment: @nich In a good implementation, you have a single "for loop" that iterates at most m times. So, I think your algorithm should take O(m) time in the worst case and Theta(m + n) memory (A needs m and X needs n blocks of memory). I might be mistaken. Please recheck it yourself later.